# C++ Style for the initialization of single variables

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style, initialization

There are a couple of differing styles when initializing automatically managed simple variables other than via assignment. I was wondering if there are any specific reasons to favour one over the other or is it just a matter of style.

Using parentheses is appealing because it feels similar to instantiating an object

```
double answer(42.0);
ComplexNumber i(0,1);
```

while using braces is appealing because it feels similar to initialising a container

```
double answer{42};
std::vector<double> i{0,1};
double i2[] = {0,1};
```

Is there any particular reason to favour one style over the other?

Comment: IIRC, `double answer{42};` is not legal.

Comment: @Code-Guru sorry I should have mentioned this is C++11, I have added the appropriate tag

Comment: I'm not up on C++11. I still don't think using `{}` with a primitive type is legal. I'd be happy (and not entirely surprised) if someone can prove me wrong, though ;-)

Comment: @Code-Guru Here you go http://ideone.com/tBsBU4 the new syntax also struck me as odd. Hence the question.

Comment: @Code-Guru Using `{}` with built-in types is legal in most (but not all) circumstances (see Boris' answer and follow the link in there). One illegal example is this `int i{42.0};` because there's a narrowing conversion from `double` to `int`.

Comment: @CassioNeri Which is odd because it works fine on GCC 4.7.2 http://ideone.com/Jdvz33 asking as seperate question

Comment: @DuncanACoulter 4.7.2 didn't implement that feature. You get a [warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=167df5a77c4bad6f3aa9107cdb69c7b9-65dc94cd4537904dae1f1ab5c131e8ce) with 4.8, and an error if you compile with Clang

Comment: @Praetorian thank you. I'm working my through Strustrup's latest book and trying to see what I may need to unlearn.

Comment: Technically, any object with a non-explicit single-argument constructor can be initialized with `someclass someobject = somevalue;` form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here: [GotW #1 : Variable Initialization](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/). It's a detailed description of answer from  H. Sutter.

H. Sutter talks above in a general sense of old and new styles of Variable Initialization.

Below is showed a quick synopsis from the article, according to your start-topic context.

---

This pair

```
double answer(42.0); // (1)
double answer{42};  // (2)
```

in fact, is similar to the next initialization example:

```
widget w(x);                // (d)
widget w{x};                // (e)
```

These are both direct initialization. However, note that the syntax `{x}` creates an `initializer_list`. If `widget` has a constructor that takes an `initializer_list`, that constructor is preferred; otherwise, if `widget` has a constructor that takes whatever type `x` is (possibly with conversions), that constructor is used.

There are two major differences that make (2, e) superior to (1, d):

- First, syntax (2, e) is unambiguous and avoids the "vexing parse". If `x` is a type name, then (1, d) is a function declaration even if there is also a variable named `x` in scope (see above), whereas (2, e) is never a function declaration.
- Second, syntax (2, e) is safer because it does not allow narrowing (a.k.a. “lossy”) conversions that are otherwise allowed for some built-in types. Consider:

  `int i1( 12.345 );           // ok: toss .345, we didn't like it anyway`

  `int i2{ 12.345 };           // error: would be lossy implicit narrowing`

Next pair

```
ComplexNumber i(0,1); // (3)
std::vector<double> i{0,1}; // (4)
```

is tied with initialization of complex objects. Both looks quite the same, but the second one helps us to avoid "vexing parse", like:

```
ComplexNumber       w( real(), img() );       // oops, vexing parse
```

Besides of that, this way make code more clear (if we use `initializer_list`, it's more clear that's initialization),
and, moreover, alleviate syntax in some cases, for instance:

```
draw_rect({ origin, selection });                  // C++11
```

Sutter guildeline is: prefer to use initialization with `{ }`, such as `vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` or `auto v = vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };`, because it’s more consistent, more correct, and avoids having to know about old-style pitfalls at all. In single-argument cases where you prefer to see only the `=` sign, such as `int i = 42`; and `auto x = anything`; omitting the braces is fine.

We can use ()-initialization for the explicit call of the special constructor.

Comment: Excellent x-ref, but your answer is in danger of being regarded as a 'link-only' answer.  It would be improved if you gave a quick synopsis of the what Herb Sutter says (roughly, if you've got C++11 and won't have to port to less modern compilers, use `{}` notation each time to avoid the 'most vexing parse').

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606848/boris)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17112872/1137388) there's another pitfall to avoid that's not mentioned in Herb's blog post.

The following code is illegal:

```
#include <initializer_list>

int main() {
  auto i{42}; // not the same as 'auto i(42);'
  ++i;
}
```

The error message raised by gcc 4.7.2 is:

> > error: no match for 'operator++' in '++i'

The reason is that `auto` deduces the type of `{42}` to be `std::inilializer_list<int>` rather than `int` as many could believe. There's no `operator ++` for `std::initializer_list<int>` and hence the error. If you replace `{42}` with `(42)` then the code compiles fine.

Comment: Interesting that error message is a real red herring.

Comment: @Cassio: I think it has a sense to show this example at Sutter page, in comment. It can improve that article and make some feedback to cpp-community in general.

Comment: @Boris. That's a good suggestion. Thanks. Unfortunately the post is closed for comments. :-(

Comment: @Boris. I have just read a more [recent post](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/07/gotw-92-solution-auto-variables-part-1/) by Herb where he explains `auto i{42};`.

Answer (score 1):

[GotW #93](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/) has a very interesting rationale for declaring everything with `auto`.