# C++ I'm expecting a narrowing conversion error but not getting it

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, gcc4.7

In the following code from [Stroustrup's book](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) we are warned against an error from a narrowing conversion which does not occur on my version GCC (4.7.2)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i1 = 7.2;
    int i2{7.2};
    cout << i1 << " " << i2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As demonstrated here [at ideone](http://ideone.com/Jdvz33) is this a bug or am I not running with the appropriate command line arguments to the compiler? Or is this meant to be a purely semantic error?

Comment: GCC is too lenient here - by default, 4.7 doesn't warn / error and needs `-Wnarrowing`, and 4.8 only warns by default and needs `-Werror=narrowing` to conform to the C++11 standard.

Comment: [A comment to your previous, related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112692/c-style-for-the-initialization-of-single-variables#comment24760489_17112692) might answer this question.

Comment: @Xeo The terms "error" and "warning" do not appear in the c++ language standards. They use the term "diagnostic", the exact interpretation of which is left to compiler implementors. So 4.8. is conforming.

Comment: @Casey: I will fight that notion! Errors should be errors, and not just nilly-willy warnings! :P

Comment: @Xeo - fight all you want, but the **language definition** says only that a diagnostic is required, and that what constitutes a diagnostic is implementation defined. The **only** time that the standard requires that something not compile is when a `#error` is triggered. That allows conforming extensions: the compiler issues a diagnostic and compiles the code to do whatever the extension is.

Comment: Use -std=c++0x when compiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With g++ 4.8.1:

```
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:8:15: warning: narrowing conversion of '7.2000000000000002e+0' from 'double' to 'int' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
     int i2{7.2};
               ^
```

I assume it's simply a bug in 4.7.2's c++11 support.

Comment: The Standard states that uniform init should *error* here, not warn.

Comment: There is no such thing as *error* in the standard. *Diagnostic* is the standard's term.

Comment: @DeadMG It states that "A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do
not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however,
they can compile and execute such programs."

Answer (score 1):

I get a narrowing warning with GCC 4.7.3 when I use -std=c++0x:

```
g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:23: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘7.2000000000000002e+0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.7.3
```

Comment: Well ideone uses 4.7.2 so I guess the behavior must have changed between minor version numbers or the warning levels on ideone are too low

Comment: It only compiles  with that flag on, if its  disabled it says the feature is unsupported  and that I should enable the flag.